# How to increase session timeout in silver light?

Tags: c#, silverlight, session

I have been trying to increase session time out in silverlight from the default timeout time.
I am setting this time in webconfig. When I try to decrease the time it works fine and session gets expired in given time. But it seems that increasing the time has no effect at all. I dont think this issue is code specific. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check the application pool advanced settings in IIS. There is an `Idle time out` and `Regular Time Interval` (Recycling) setting.

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure both client and server side config files ? Both should be consistant, otherwise it works according to lower value.

Check for configurations on this [site](http://www.fredmastro.com/post/silverlight-timeout-issues-from-wcfe280a6-exceeded-the-allotted-timeout.aspx)